# CSS to change color of tab on a Bootstrap Tab Control when hovering over the tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is the html code for a vertically aligned Boostrap tab control - sample (bare bones - this is a working sample).  It appears that the default color of a tab when hovering over it is a light gray color (I am guessing from boostrap.min.css).  Is there a way I could change the color from light gray to something else in my own css?  to like override the default color (if that is what it is) ? What is the css for that?

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
            .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
            .tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
              float: none;
            }

            .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
            .tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
              min-width: 74px;
              margin-right: 0;
              margin-bottom: 3px;
            }

            .tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
              float: left;
              margin-right: 19px;
              border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
            }

            .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
              margin-right: -1px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
                 -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
                      border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
            }

            .tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
            .tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
            .tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {                                
              border-color: red blue red red;
              *border-right-color: lime;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <div class="container">    
        <div><h3>Tabs - vertical</h3>
          <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li style="background-color:orange;"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
              <li style="background-color:orange;" class="active"><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
              <li style="background-color:orange;"><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
             <div class="tab-pane" id="a"> --A) testing row A</div>
             <div class="tab-pane  active" id="b"> --B) testing row B</div>
             <div class="tab-pane" id="c"> --C) testing row C </div>
                </div>
              </div>      
            </div>    
        </div>   
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it have to be CSS can it use Javascript ?

Comment: Can you setup a JsFiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-color?v=control):

```
.tabs-left > .nav > li > a:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets, so rules that are specified further down the page override rules stated above. You can change these in a couple of ways, though, when you don't have access to a stylesheet coming from someone else (like bootstrap).

1) The most specific rule wins. So,

```
h1 span:hover {
  color: blue;
}

span:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

would mean the text surrounded by a `span` inside an `h1` tag is blue when you hover over it, even though the `span` style was declared afterwards. `h1 span` is more specific than `span`, so it's weighted more heavily.

2) You can slap an `!important` at the end of a property declaration, but this is usually to be avoided unless you have to. So,

```
h1 span:hover {
  color: blue;
}

span:hover {
  color: red !important;
}
```

would mean that text is red, because `!important` is much stronger and harder to overwrite.

So, for your case, you just need to find out the style that is being applied to your tab on hover (right click on it and check the styles pane to see how it's being targeted), and then write your own rule in your stylesheet that uses a greater degree of specificity than what bootstrap is coming in with.

Also, it looks like you've got `background-color` set as an inline style for those orange tabs. Inline styles, like `!important` are weighed very heavily, as well, so you'll have a harder time manipulating those with just CSS. I'd try and move those into classes, if you can (unless you only did that for the sake of this question, then ignore this part).

Comment: Thank you for this insight.  I have applied it as suggested.  Much better way to go for the default background color.